# select multiple columns of single row as elements of array

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with 100 columns called like col_1, col_2, .. col_100
is there a way to select values of that columns of single into an array of 100 elements?

(Oracle 10.2)

Comment: Since SQL itself does deal with arrays what programming language do you have in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a brute force method. There's probably a more elegant way, or at least one that will cut down on typing. The example uses five columns rather than 100.

```
DECLARE
  -- Change VARCHAR2(10) in the next line to your col_1 .. col_100 type
  TYPE My100Array IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(10) INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  myVals My100Array;
  indx NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT 'These', 'are', 'the', 'column', 'values'
     INTO myVals(1), myVals(2), myVals(3), myVals(4), myVals(5)
     FROM DUAL;
   FOR INDX IN 1..5 LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(indx || ': ' || myVals(indx));
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Here's the output when I run this:

```
1: These
2: are
3: the
4: column
5: values
```

Of course, this will be a bit tough with 100 columns, but once you get the query out of the way you'll have the array as you want it.

Comment: without being able to use `UNPIVOT` this is the best answer.

Comment: actually given that you know the number of columns using `type my100array is VARRAY(100) of VARCHAR2(10);` would also work

Answer (score 2):

you could just select them like:

```
SQL> create type foo as table of number; -- or varray, as you wish.
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> select foo(l.a, l.b, l.c) foo from your_tab l;

FOO
-----------------
FOO(1, 2, 3)
```

etc..

Answer (score 0):

Another example:

```
DECLARE 
   CURSOR c_data IS
   SELECT * FROM scott.emp; -- replace emp table with your_table

   TYPE t_source_tab IS TABLE OF scott.emp%ROWTYPE;
   l_tab    t_source_tab;
 BEGIN
   SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO l_tab FROM scott.emp;

   -- display values in array --
   FOR i IN l_tab.FIRST ..l_tab.LAST 
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (l_tab(i).hiredate ||chr(9)||l_tab(i).empno  ||chr(9)||l_tab(i).ename);
   END LOOP;   
 END;
 /
```

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you want to unpivot your data..

unfortunately `UNPIVOT` was only added in 11g (not 10.2)
you could manually unpivot but one of the other solutions would work better i think.

However, if you were on 11g or later you could try this

```
create table my_table (col1 number,col2 number, col3 number);
Table MY_TABLE created.

insert into my_table values (4,5,6);
1 row inserted.

select * from my_table;
      COL1       COL2       COL3
---------- ---------- ----------
         4          5          6

select val from my_table unpivot ( val for col in ( col1,col2,col3));

       VAL
----------
         4
         5
         6
```

from there is trivial to select into an single column array

```
DECLARE 
   CURSOR c_data IS
   select val from my_table unpivot ( val for col in ( col1,col2,col3));


   TYPE t_source_tab IS TABLE OF c_data%ROWTYPE;
   l_tab    t_source_tab;
 BEGIN

    open c_data;
    fetch c_data bulk collect into l_tab;
    close c_data;

   -- display values in array --
   FOR i IN l_tab.FIRST ..l_tab.LAST 
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (l_tab(i).val);
   END LOOP;   
 END;
 /
```